# Minimum length of PKI key for signature

Tags: rsa, key-size, dsa

I am looking for data which shows how time it would take to brute force (or crack by any other method) different sizes of RSA/DSA keys used for a digital signature.

I am looking to use as small a key as possible & hence looking for how long a signature generated by it can be cracked.

Comment: Your question says RSA, the tags say DSA.

Comment: I require this info for both - updated.

Comment: 1) If you care about key size, don't use RSA or DSA. ECC has much smaller keys. 2) Key size by itself is meaningless since it can be trivially reduced, increasing the signature size by the same amount. Do you actually care about the sum of the size of key and signature?

Comment: As some of the answers to the above explain, DSA key size required is approximately the same.